# remove extra spaces within href in php

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Any suggestion to remove the space within the href like

```
href="http://www.tra nslationservices24.c om/russian/russian-t ranslation-services">
```

There is a space between `"tra"`, `"nslationservice24.c"` and `"om/..."`, no space in database in href.

Comment: Please clarify EVERYTHING

Comment: I fail to see what this has to do with PHP? Please enlighten?

Comment: Thanks , It automatically place space with in the href double quotest when i show the record from database like "goog le.com", space between g and l ,

Comment: Seems like you should remove some of that automation ?

Comment: here is code that replace preg_replace('/[ ]{2,}/',"",$row->bodyarticle);but when href come it place space automatically , within the href="halflink + space+ remaining">

Comment: what's this "it"? PHP does not mangle your text unless you tell it to.

Comment: http://universitytwig.com/article/detail/Professional_Russian_Translation_Agency_and_its_Role , please check article detail when click more then href showing space and not clickable.

Comment: @irfan We need the server side code, _that_ isn't visible to clients.  In other words, post your php interaction with the database, hide your passwords and such.  We can't see it otherwise, only what it results in, and that is no help to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove spaces in a string with a regex, and if it's an elements href attribute, you'll need to get and set the attribute by using a selector and some javascript, something like:

```
element.href = element.href.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Fixing it on the serverside is probably a better idea, but without more code it's hard to write an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in PHP:

```
$href = str_replace(" ","","href-string here");
```

Comment: I just need to remove the space between the href="halfstring + space +remaining" , not from the whole string

Comment: You didn't tell that your link is not alone but with other string :/